Under which circumstances is multi-task learning sensible?
Given certain tasks with samples $y_1(\vec{x}), ... y_n(\vec{x})$
When can we expect multi-task learning to be a sensible approach (i.e. giving "better" results than training n independent models)?
I do understand the following:

looking for a "good" performance for tasks 1..n is inherently a multi-objective optimization problem and therefore there will be infinitely many Pareto optimal solutions (incomparably good solutions, requiring additional indifference curves to select a single best optimization solution)
though a tough multi-objective optimization problem, I can imagine a situation where the conditional mean estimators for all tasks improve through multi-target learning or have less variance while still being unbiased (when Bootstrapping the test train datasets). Maybe this is in the sense similar to the Cramer Rao bound https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound

Now for neural networks and gradient descent-like based optimization,I came up with the following thoughts:

While in practice, people train "embedding models" which they then concatenate with task heads for the different tasks 1..n it seems quite lucky if only the presence of this joint embedding (a common neural backbone) is helping to achieve a better performance in all the tasks (although this could implicitly work as a kind of regularization, it feels more like a burden avoiding the best feature extraction for a given task in the common backbone...)
shouldn't the multitask learning mostly be beneficial when there is a high covariance structure between targets 1..n (so should I check for this prior to starting a multi-target learning model)
would it be beneficial to exploit such a covariance structure in the targets through the multidimensional Gaussian negative log likelihood loss?

What else is there to consider?
PS: https://openreview.net/forum?id=SylzhkBtDB "Understanding and Improving Information Transfer in Multi-Task Learning" seems related, but raises different points
